# Internet doesn't work when I use a specific website on a particular browser

Tags: macos, firefox, internet, website

Whenever I log in to brain.fm from Firefox, my internet slows down. It goes from 50MB/s down to 1-5 MB/s.

I have the most up to date Firefox and I tried it with a fresh install without any add-ons.

I do not have this affect when I use brain.fm from Safari. This is something that I can reproduce consistently. I have the problem on different computers on the same network.

I'm wondering if there's something fishy happening. How can I debug this further?

Comment: When you go to brain.fm, are you already signed in? Does it start playing anything? When I go to brain.fm, I am shown an introductory homepage with info about the product and an option to sign up or sign in. I'm curious if this problem occurs pre-sign in, or not. Please sign-out of the website, and try again, if that is the case. Based on previous comments you've tried a different computer, and different internet connections, and you've tried running with no-addons and reinstalling Firefox but the problem occurs still. Therefore, I should be able to reproduce the issue on my end.

Comment: I wonder if you're making a leap between the problem occurring on my network and the problem supposed to be appearing on your network. I'm using it signed in.

Comment: I’m not making a leap. It’s what you said. You were asked, “Are you able to reproduce the result when you connect the two laptops on a **different** WiFi network?” And you answered, “Yes I’m able to repro under those circumstances.” You should [edit] your post and improve it so that it is clear what you have, and have not, done to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. I have the problem on different computers on the same network.

Comment: Open performance monitor and see if you see a steady boost in network throughout when you go to the site. Your change in performance is indicative of network load. An application like Fiddler or Wireshark can better show what the usage is. So can F12 developer tools.

Comment: I can see the websites in Fiddler and Wireshark but I don't know how to tell how it affects network load

Comment: You’re looking for continued, related activity, when there shouldn’t be and then identify what that activity is. It takes some experience probably. Question, is it the upstream or downstream that gets slow?

Comment: It's the downstream that gets slow. There is related activity and it's because the website has quotes that load up on the screen as it plays music at the same time (I think)

Answer (score 1):

That happens to me when i am downloading through Chrome as it suddenly locks itself to 2MB down speed, and if it goes lower on my WIFI, then it goes lower.

I have tried everything as well on chrome, more than you mentioned above and nothing works. Since i am not familiar with MAC, i cannot help that much, but CMD and PowerShell on Windows 10 allow me to change the actually permissions and limitations on chrome. You could use the terminal, but i do not know anything about the language.

Something that might also work is checking the settings to see if there are any limitations that Firefox has placed. Just look around its settings, and probably advanced setting, to see if you can fix the issue.

It could also be the way that Firefox is handling the Cookies, so try and delete them.